# Add up input boxes values and compare to another

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of input boxes to denote cash being paid by denomination. And another readonly one to show the amount thats supposed to be taken from the till. It works fine, but unfortunately people sometimes don't enter the correct amounts and the cash in the till doesn't balance. So I want to calculate all the input boxes and compare that total to what it should be, then if they don't match throw an error. If they do then continue.

On top of that people are entering dodgy amounts, like 321 in the '100s' field, when only multiples of the denomination should be entered, eg 300. Even the coins they enter stuff like 350 instead of 3.50 or 3.33 when our smallest coin is a 5c.

So I have this code for the boxes, but keep getting lost doing the javascript.

```
    <?php

    print '
<table cellspacing=1 cellpadding=0>
<tbody>
    <col width=140>
    <col width=320>
    <col width=34>
    <col width=140>
    <col width=320>

    <tr class="view">
        <td class="viewN">Transfer ID</td>
        <td class="viewL">' . $tran['transfer_id'] . '</td>
        <td colspan=3></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="view">
        <td colspan=5></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="view">
        <td class="viewN">Recipient</td>
        <td class="viewL">' . $tran['rcp_name'] . '</td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="viewN"></td>
        <td class="viewN"></td>
    </tr>' . "\n";

if ($tran['paid_type'] != 'layby') {
    print '
    <tr class="view">
        <td class="viewN">ID1 type</td>
        <td><select name="rcp_id1_type" tabindex="24"><option value="Passport" selected>Passport</option><option value="Drivers">Driver\'s License</option><option value="bank">Bank Account</option><option value="Credit Card">Credit Card</option><option value="Govt Id">Government Issued ID</option><option value="NUS">Student ID</option><option value="NPF">NPF</option><option value="Pension">Pension</option><option value="other">Other</option></select></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="viewN"></td>
        <td class="viewN"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="view">
        <td class="viewN">ID1 reference</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="rcp_id1_reference" style="width:300px;" maxlength="255"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="viewN"></td>
        <td class="viewN"></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="view">
        <td class="viewN">Currency</td>
        <td><input type="text" readonly name="rcp_ccy" value="' . $tran['rcp_ccy'] . '"></td>
        <td>Payout</td>
        <td><input type="text" readonly name="rcp_amount" value="' . $tran['rcp_amount'] . '"></td>
        <td class="viewN"></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="view">
        <td class="viewN">$100s</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cashed_100" value="0"></td>
        <td>$50s</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cashed_50" value="0"></td>
        <td class="viewN"></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="view">
        <td class="viewN">$20s</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cashed_20" value="0"></td>
        <td>$10s</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cashed_10" value="0"></td>
        <td class="viewN"></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="view">
        <td class="viewN">$5s</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cashed_5" value="0"></td>
        <td>Coins</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cashed_coins" value="0"></td>
        <td class="viewN"></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="view">
        <span id="result"></span>
    </tr>
</tbody>
    
    ' . "\n";
}

print '
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>' . "\n";
?>
```

So basically I want to check the values inputted are multiples of the denomination, and get the sum of the values and compare them to the readonly amount value and give an error if it's not a multiple and if the sum is incorrect.

Please assist

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+sum+input+fields+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please post RENDERED HTML along with any javascript you tried

Comment: @mplungjan should I split it into 3 questions? How to check the amounts are multiples. How to check coins are sane. How to check sum agrees with correct amount? JS isn't my thing

Comment: Not really necessary, but effort is appreciated. See however my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP is generating invalid HTML. Please see the relevant PHP at the bottom of the answer.

The JavaScript below goes inside `<script>...</script>` tags in the head or in an external file with extension .js

An external JS file is loaded using `<script src="nameOfExternalFile.js"></script>` instead of the above

Note  I used [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to format the message into a cell at the bottom of the table which will have red text if error

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // when the page loads
  const amt = +document.querySelector("[name='rcp_amount']").value;
  const output = document.getElementById("result");
  document.querySelector("table tbody").addEventListener("input", () => {
    let total = 0;
    let result = [];
    document.querySelectorAll('[name^=cashed]').forEach(inp => {
      const denom = +inp.name.split('_')[1];
      const val = +inp.value;
      if (!isNaN(denom)) { // ignore "coins" denom
        total += val;
        if (val % denom !== 0) result.push(`The denomination ${denom} does not match the amount inputted`)
      }
    });
    let error = result.length > 0; // error found
    if (total !== amt) {
      result.push(`Total ${total} does not match ${amt}`)
      error = true; // regardless
    } else {
      result.push(`Total ${total} matches ${amt}`);
    }
    output.innerHTML = result.join("<br/>");
    output.classList.toggle("error", error); // red if error
  });

});
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing=1 cellpadding=0>
  <colgroup>
    <col width=140>
    <col width=320>
    <col width=34>
    <col width=140>
    <col width=320>
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="view">
      <td class="viewN">Transfer ID</td>
      <td class="viewL">ID 1</td>
      <td colspan=3></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="view">
      <td colspan=5></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="view">
      <td class="viewN">Recipient</td>
      <td class="viewL">Recipient 1</td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="viewN"></td>
      <td class="viewN"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="view">
      <td class="viewN">ID1 type</td>
      <td>
        <select name="rcp_id1_type" tabindex="24">
          <option value="Passport" selected>Passport</option>
          <option value="Drivers">Driver's License</option>
          <option value="bank">Bank Account</option>
          <option value="Credit Card">Credit Card</option>
          <option value="Govt Id">Government Issued ID</option>
          <option value="NUS">Student ID</option>
          <option value="NPF">NPF</option>
          <option value="Pension">Pension</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="viewN"></td>
      <td class="viewN"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="view">
      <td class="viewN">ID1 reference</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="rcp_id1_reference" style="width:300px;" maxlength="255"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="viewN"></td>
      <td class="viewN"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="view">
      <td class="viewN">Currency</td>
      <td><input type="text" readonly name="rcp_ccy" value="USD"></td>
      <td>Payout</td>
      <td><input type="text" readonly name="rcp_amount" value="350"></td>
      <td class="viewN"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="view">
      <td class="viewN">$100s</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="cashed_100" value="0"></td>
      <td>$50s</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="cashed_50" value="0"></td>
      <td class="viewN"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="view">
      <td class="viewN">$20s</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="cashed_20" value="0"></td>
      <td>$10s</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="cashed_10" value="0"></td>
      <td class="viewN"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="view">
      <td class="viewN">$5s</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="cashed_5" value="0"></td>
      <td>Coins</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="cashed_coins" value="0"></td>
      <td class="viewN"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="view">
      <td colspan="5" id="result"></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the PHP needed to create the above. Notice I removed the print and use <?= to insert variables where needed - I had to make a test array for the vars since I do not want to create a database

The script and PHP outputting HTML can be tested at https://plungjan.name/SO/till/

```
<?php /* here goes whatever you need to access the database */ 

// For testing I created an associative array
$tran = array(
    'transfer_id' => 'T12345',
    'rcp_name' => 'John Doe',
    'paid_type' => 'not layby',
    'rcp_ccy' => 'USD',
    'rcp_amount' => 1000
); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Till control</title>
    <script src="tillcontrol.js"></script>
    <style>
      .error {
        color: red;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table cellspacing=1 cellpadding=0>
      <colgroup>
        <col width=140>
        <col width=320>
        <col width=34>
        <col width=140>
        <col width=320>
      </colgroup>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="view">
          <td class="viewN">Transfer ID</td>
          <td class="viewL"><?= $tran['transfer_id'] ?></td>
          <td colspan=3></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="view">
          <td colspan=5></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="view">
          <td class="viewN">Recipient</td>
          <td class="viewL"><?= $tran['rcp_name'] ?></td>
          <td></td>
          <td class="viewN"></td>
          <td class="viewN"></td>
        </tr>
        <?php if ($tran['paid_type'] != 'layby') { ?>
        <tr class="view">
          <td class="viewN">ID1 type</td>
          <td><select name="rcp_id1_type" tabindex="24">
              <option value="Passport" selected>Passport</option>
              <option value="Drivers">Driver's License</option>
              <option value="bank">Bank Account</option>
              <option value="Credit Card">Credit Card</option>
              <option value="Govt Id">Government Issued ID</option>
              <option value="NUS">Student ID</option>
              <option value="NPF">NPF</option>
              <option value="Pension">Pension</option>
              <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select></td>
          <td></td>
          <td class="viewN"></td>
          <td class="viewN"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="view">
          <td class="viewN">ID1 reference</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="rcp_id1_reference" style="width:300px;" maxlength="255"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td class="viewN"></td>
          <td class="viewN"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="view">
          <td class="viewN">Currency</td>
          <td><input type="text" readonly name="rcp_ccy" value="<?= $tran['rcp_ccy'] ?>"></td>
          <td>Payout</td>
          <td><input type="text" readonly name="rcp_amount" value="<?= $tran['rcp_amount'] ?>"></td>
          <td class="viewN"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="view">
          <td class="viewN">$100s</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="cashed_100" value="0"></td>
          <td>$50s</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="cashed_50" value="0"></td>
          <td class="viewN"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="view">
          <td class="viewN">$20s</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="cashed_20" value="0"></td>
          <td>$10s</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="cashed_10" value="0"></td>
          <td class="viewN"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="view">
          <td class="viewN">$5s</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="cashed_5" value="0"></td>
          <td>Coins</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="cashed_coins" value="0"></td>
          <td class="viewN"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="view">
          <td colspan="5" id="result"></td>
        </tr>
        <? } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: THat looks great. Way over my head though, I was messing around with inline js onchange and just made a mess. How would I run that? Is it js? Not jquery or something else?

Comment: Plain JS using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) using a [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors) on the name starting with "cashed"

Comment: Yes, I'm slowly working it out by looking things up. Can't see how the console log works though, I've only used alerts, not sure if I have a console

Comment: Wow, that works great. I want an alert for the error, or even just an alert message saying it's wrong and to input correct values on a button press. It doesn't have to be in real time

Comment: Ok, I updated to give a string result in a span. I used [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to format the message

Comment: Thats genius.... I'm learning a lot just going through it. I'm sure I can make it work in my form

Comment: I've been trying 2 hours to make this work on my file is it because it's php? Or maybe because it's a require file inside another?

Comment: I have the whole php file without needing to inspect, I can copy but where would I paste it

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Also no need to print `\n` in the middle of the table.  Here is the PHP that **I** suggest: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/eqd61puy/

Comment: Sorry thats what my file looks like, The viewN does nothing except font so it's not necessary. My file is php not html

Comment: I have posted the PHP here too at the bottom of my answer

Comment: Still can't get it working, unsure if the js is running, I put it in an external file, since the head is not on this page. Even when I put it in the header it doesn't work

Comment: See the updated PHP including external JS file in my answer and look here https://plungjan.name/SO/till/ to test that exact PHP. The file `tillcontrol.js` is in the same folder as the index.php